# Subtract values from one column based on values in another (TSQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregate-functions

[image]

I have table where I need to subtract values in one column based on conditions applied to the other. For example, I want to subtract values with code `fst` and `trd`, meaning `(12 - 23)`.
I don't want to declare separate variables. Is it possible to make this with a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when code = 'fst' then value else - value end)
from t
where code in ('fst', 'trd');
```

Assuming you have only one row for each code, you can also use a `join`:

```
select tf.value - tt.value
from t tf join
     t tt
     on tf.code = 'fst' and tt.code = 'trd'
```

Comment: You say this is one method. Can you offer a substitute? Thank you.

Comment: What about a case when I want to divide these same values? I did it with the second option you gave in your answer. I am not sure it is the optimal decision

Comment: @Yana . . . Then you would have a different question . . . but you can use:  `sum(case when code = 'fst' then value end) / sum(case when value = 'trd' then value end)`.